# Delphi date comparison

Tags: delphi, date

What is the difference between the two functions "IsSameDay" and "SameDate" in the Delphi DateUtils library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The start of the day before day zero is `TDateTime(-1.0)`. Noon of that day is `TDateTime(-1.5)`.

```
IsSameDay(-1.5, -1); // False
SameDate(-1.5, -1); // True
```

For positive dates, the functions are equivalent.